# custom math function using php

Tags: php

I'm not so good with PHP. I have a function which I'm trying to execute, but am unable to do so. I'm trying this for quite some time now.

```
$init_val = ($price/120) * 20;
$mid_val = $price - $init_val;
//$final_value = $mid_value - 35% of $mid_val     // want to execute this logic
//$final_value = $mid_value - ($mid_val * 35%);   // this gives error
//$final_value = $mid_value - 35%;                // same error
```

The error given is:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in /var/www/site1/function.php on line 51

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `$mid_val * 0.35`. `%` is for [mod](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.mod.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use percentage values like that in PHP. The `%` symbol is reserved for modulus operations. Try this instead:

```
$final_value = $mid_value - ($mid_val * 0.35);
```

That would give you 65% of `$mid_value` in `$final_value`

Comment: Thank you for giving the right answer and also explaining where I was going wrong :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `%` as a math function:

```
$final_value = $mid_value - ($mid_val * 0.35);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$final_value = $mid_value - ($mid_val * 0.35);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code *the idea* of percent, create a function

```
function percent($value) {
    return $value / 100;
}
```

then you can write

```
$final_value = $mid_value - $mid_val * percent(35);
```

(no need of parentheses around `$midval * percent(35)` since `*` has a higher precedence than `-` ([see this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)))

`%` [is the modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).